# Can't import EvinceView in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can do

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

but when i'm trying to do the same with EvinceView makes error

```
>>> from gi.repository import EvinceView
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\importer.py", line 53, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name EvinceView, introspection typelib not found
>>>
```

In linux works well, but not in windows

What's the reason? Missing package or it's impossible?

Thanks a lot